# Javascript dispatchEvent - Why is it needed?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have code which is written:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    //code here;
}, false);
```

And it works fine...but I am being told to add by the Mozilla dev page:

```
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Can anyone tell me why I need to add the dispatch and why it is working without it (what the dispatch actually does would also be very useful!).

W3C also recommends in the specification to remove an event when done with it, but for an orientation change it could happen at any time, is it OK to leave it there?

Much obliged for any help.

Comment: Waht is `elem`? What is `event`? Which MDN page?

Comment: This page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

elem is just a place holder for whatever variable you are dealing with, event again is just a place holder for an event...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`addEventListener` says that, on the object (`window` in your example) you want to react whenever that object dispatches and event with the a given type (e. g. `orientationchange`)

You are listening to an event from an object.

`dispatchEvent` is what you call if you want to send or trigger an event. Internally, the browser is doing this whenever the user rotates their device, which triggers `orientationchange` . In this specific example, you don't need to trigger this manually unless you need to do so for testing.

`removeEventListener` does what you'd expect, and makes it so that you no longer are listening for triggered events. It is usually good to do this if you know you no longer want to listen to the event or that the event will no longer be fired so that you can free up memory resources. For your case, it seems like you don't need to do this.

Here is more information about [DOM and JavaScript Events, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).

Comment: Great, thanks! So in a normal situation without a dispatch the event will not trigger? Does 'removeEventListener' simply stop the previous dispatch so to add it again all I need to do is dispatch again?

Comment: I think "normal situation" entirely depends on which events you are talking about on which objects. `removeEventListener` removes the handler for the event. To add it again, use `addEventListener`. If you dispatch an event and nothing is listening, nothing will happen.

Comment: OK, so it depends on the events and or objects being discussed...is dispatched used to trigger the event in say an onClick for example? Also, when I execute addEventListener I presume I am adding it to a list or object somewhere and it remains active during the session, is this correct? If so do you know where it is added? Thanks!

Comment: Many of the events like `onClick` will be dispatched natively by the browser. `addEventListener` does add your handler to a list somewhere, but I don't know off the top of my head if there is a way to access it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

dispatch *meaning* **send off to a destination or for a purpose.**

dispatchEvent is the last step of the create-init-dispatch process, which is used for dispatching events into the implementation's event model.

```
EventTarget.dispatchEvent
```

Dispatches an `Event` at the specified `EventTarget`, invoking the affected `EventListeners` in the appropriate order. The normal event processing rules (including the capturing and optional bubbling phase) apply to events dispatched manually with `dispatchEvent()`